# Rewrite rules not working htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get, url-rewriting

I have the following htaccess rewrite rules

```
RewriteRule ^shows-watch/(.*).html?$ show.php?name=$1 
RewriteRule ^shows-watch/(.*)/season-(.*).html?$ show.php?name=$1&season=$2
RewriteRule ^shows-watch/(.*)/season-(.*)/episode-(.*).html?$ show.php?name=$1&season=$2&episode=$3
```

Now the thing is, the first rewrite rule works just fine

```
RewriteRule ^shows-watch/(.*).html?$ show.php?name=$1
```

It's just when I try using the others, only name get variable is being passed and not

```
$_GET['season']
```

or

```
$_GET['episode']
```

i know it's most likely something simple I'm missing or have done, but I just can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^shows-watch/([^/]+)/season-([^/]+)/episode-([^/]+).html?$ show.php?name=$1&season=$2&episode=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^shows-watch/([^/]+)/season-([^/]+).html?$ show.php?name=$1&season=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^shows-watch/([^.]+)\.html?$ show.php?name=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The order is very important so they don't overlap you also need the `L` flag to stop when needed.

This assumes your .htaccess is on the root folder of your domain along with the show.php file and that you are accessing it like this:

```
domain.com/shows-watch/Show Name.html
domain.com/shows-watch/Show Name/season-1.html
domain.com/shows-watch/Show Name/season-1/episode-10.html
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line gets all the links because it matches all the links.
Try reverse the order:

```
RewriteRule ^shows-watch/(.*)/season-(.*)/episode-(.*).html?$ show.php?name=$1&season=$2&episode=$3    
RewriteRule ^shows-watch/(.*)/season-(.*).html?$ show.php?name=$1&season=$2
RewriteRule ^shows-watch/(.*).html?$ show.php?name=$1
```

**Or** you can exclude slashes like this:

```
RewriteRule ^shows-watch/([^/]*).html?$ show.php?name=$1 
RewriteRule ^shows-watch/([^/]*)/season-([^/]*).html?$ show.php?name=$1&season=$2
RewriteRule ^shows-watch/([^/]*)/season-([^/]*)/episode-([^/]*).html?$ show.php?name=$1&season=$2&episode=$3
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't make a difference

Comment: Try it again, I tested it on my localhost and it worked well.